# Kakuro and Subset Sum, where the superset contains consecutive positive integers and subsets are of fixed size k

Tags: algorithm, recursion, subset-sum

I'm working on a Kakuro Game in java. Kakuro is a game kind of similar to sudoku. 
[image: Kakuro Example]

The goal of Kakuro is to fill in those blank blocks with integer from 1 to 9 such that there are no duplicate numbers in each "region" and that all numbers in the blank blocks in the region sum up to the number in the "hintblock" in the region. The examples of regions are marked red in the picture above.

Now what I'm trying to do is to write a AI that can automatically solve a given kakuro puzzle. This first requires that you need to find all possible combinations of K number of elements from integer set of range (1,9), such that the sum of those K elements is equal to the number indicated in the "hintblock" in that region.(K in this case is the number of blanks blocks in that region) This is a variation of the "Subset problem", except that the superset is much more uniform(consecutive integers from 1-9) and that the subset is of fixed size K. 
What's even nicer is that the range of the superset can be reduced before hand. For example, see the block at the right part of the picture. The sum in this case is 24 and K is 3. By choosing an arbitrary block in this region and assuming that all other blocks are at their largest value possible, we can infer that arbitrary block must be larger than or equal to (24-(9+8))=7. We can do the same for maximum value by calculating (24-(1+2))=21, which doesn't matter because 21>9. Thus, the superset becomes {7,8,9}.

This region is a easy case because K = Superset size. However, if K is much smaller than superset size, checking all the combinations will (I'm not sure)cause calculation of (SuperSize-K)! time. This is inefficient. My question now is that is there any variations of the solution to the **Subset sum Problem** that is most suitable for this case? I code in java, but any programming language is welcome, including SPL and BrainF*ck.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2<sup>9</sup>=512 subsets of the set of integers from 1 to 9. (Actually only 502 of these are interesting because sets of size 0 and 1 never occur, afaik.) It's pretty easy to precompute these and organize them by sum (between 3 and 45, inclusive) and size. Then it's just a simple lookup to get the target set.

In the case of the standard 9-integer Kakuro, no setsize/sum combination has more than 12 possible solutions; the two combinations with 12 solutions are k=5/sum=25 and k=4/sum=20. (This duality is not accidental, with the result that you could get away with storing half of the precomputed sets. For a given `n` -- in this case 9--, any solution for `k` numbers summing to `s` can be converted to a solution for `n-k` numbers summing to `n*(n+1)/2 - s` by simply taking the complement of every subset.)

However, as `n` increases, the maximum number of subsets increases exponentially. I computed the maximum up to 30, using this Python3 "one-liner":

```
for j in range(9,31):
  print(j, Counter((len(k),sum(k))
                   for k in combinations(range(1,j+1), j//2)
                  ).most_common(1))
```

The last two values took a few seconds to compute, so this is definitely not the most efficient strategy for enumerating the possibilities. I cleaned the output up a bit for readability.

```
 N       k      sum       count
--      --      ---       -----
 9       4       20          12
10       5       28          20
11       5       31          32
12       6       39          58
13       6       42          94
14       7       52         169
15       7       56         289
16       8       68         526
17       8       72         910
18       9       86        1667
19       9       90        2934
20      10      105        5448
21      10      110        9686
22      11      126       18084
23      11      132       32540
24      12      150       61108
25      12      156      110780
26      13      175      208960
27      13      182      381676
28      14      203      723354
29      14      210     1328980
30      15      233     2527074
```

It seems to me that the huge number of possibilities makes it much more difficult to generate a Kakuro with a complete solution. Of course, you could avoid most of the possible k/sum combinations, but it still seems like the puzzle itself has a built-in unscalability.

(**Note:** This is [Sequence A277218](https://oeis.org/A277218) in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences; it is related to [Sequence A055606](https://oeis.org/A055606), which has to do with [Magic Carpets](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL3/KEITH/carpet.html).)

Comment: This is a great idea and I'll definitely give it a try! However, what if the number is bigger? Assuming that the integer set ranges from 1 to 30, how well will this method still work?

Comment: It would just barely work for n==30. You can save half the storage through symmetry (every set of size k and sum s is the inverse of a set of size n-k and sum n(n+1)/2-s); if you represent a set as a four-byte bit mask, you'd need 2GB to hold all of them. But it is probably not the optimal solution. Otoh, unique-solution kakuros with n==30 are not going to be easy to find, unless you fill in a lot of the squares, and finding a solution might be difficult.

Comment: Your answer is very insightful and helpful! N=30 would definitely create too much complexity. So now if I want to limit N to 9 or 15, the best solution is precomputing the solutions, as you mentioned, right? I'm thinking about organizing those precomputed subsets in a 2d List or Array based on both their size(k) and their sums. And whenever I need to find solutions, I just use the size and sum to quickly find potential solutions. What do you think about this idea? I am fairly new to programming in general, but my guess is that this is similar to a hash table? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ptolemorphism: yes, that's the basic idea. There are lots of ways of storing the data, but it really isn't a lot of data so you should start with something really simple. A 2D list would work fine. You can always optimize later if it turns out to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ignoring subset sum and instead treating this as a constraint satisfaction problem.  And my first pass would be a backtracking algorithm with the optimization that the next guess is made for the square with the fewest possibilities.

Do note that this is an NP-hard problem.  **No** solution will scale well.

Comment: What do you think about the method of using rows and columns to narrow down potential solutions at the block where they intersect? Do you think that will be a working approach?(Or at least make solving the problem easier)

Comment: @Ptolemorphism Right.  Don't think in terms of "here is the set of all values for this row".  Think in terms of, "For each cell, here are the possibilities.  Then you try a guess for a cell, which will change the possibilities for the other cells.  Then if you run into 0 possibilities, that is a failure and you need to backtrack to try again.